# Flutter Status bar color In Redmi poco devices

Tags: flutter

In android, we had an option

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="p">false</item>
```

But in flutter I cannot find an equivalent.

If I set the status bar color to any color it works. But if I set it to White it shows black in redmi and poco devices. I have tried 3 different way to set status bar color one is given below

```
 SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  statusBarColor: Colors.white
));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check if the Dark Mode is turned `on` on the device?

Comment: Even if dark mode is on the status bar color should be white.  In native android development we use forcedarkallowed false to fix that problem.

Comment: Yes, I am also a native android and iOS developer, but this is a recognised problem in Xiaomi/Redmi/Poco devices that when `android:forceDarkAllowed` is not set to false, the system will turn almost all white colours to black (Personal Experience from Using Xiaomi devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the solution, I just natively added

```
<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="p">false</item>
```

To values-night styles.xml To both launchtheme and normaltheme.

then

> `"flutter clean"`

Without flutter clean it will not work.